# Flag NaN values rearest neighbor with xarray

Tags: python

I am working on netcdf dataset that sometimes have a large cloud coverage, materialized by `NaN`. Is there a way to flag the `n` neighbors of `NaN` patches ? Namely, go from this:

```
array([[0.7, 0.3, 0.9, 0.2, 0.6, 0.5, 0.2, 1. ],
       [0.2, 1. , 0.2, 0.2, 0.7, 0. , 1. , 0.2],
       [0.6, 0.4, 0.8, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 0.7],
       [0.5, 1. , 0.3, 0.8, 0.2, 0.9, 0.2, 0.1],
       [nan, nan, 1. , 0.7, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8, 0.6],
       [nan, nan, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.8, 0.2, 0.8]])
```

To this (for `n = 2`):

```
array([[0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [1. , 1. , 1. , 1. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [1. , 1. , 1. , 1. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [nan, nan, 1. , 1. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [nan, nan, 1. , 1. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ]])
```

I tried using `xarray.dataarray.rolling()` but it does not support `np.isnan()` (see error bellow).

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, you can do similar thing with NumPy, it does not matter whether you originally used xarray or something else to read in the data.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
# ---------------------
import numpy as np
from pylab import subplot,pcolormesh,show
# ---------------------
n=1;
ny,nx = 20,20
# ---------------------
# some random matrix:
dataout = np.random.random((ny,nx))

n_nan = 5
# some random places for nan values:
ii = np.array(np.random.random((n_nan,1))*nx,dtype='int32')
jj = np.array(np.random.random((n_nan,1))*ny,dtype='int32')

dataout[jj,ii] = np.nan
nanmask = np.array(np.isnan(dataout),dtype='float32');
# ---------------------------------------------------------
#pcolormesh(dataout);show()
# ---------------------------------------------------------
# let us update the nan-mask:
JJ,II = np.where(np.isnan(dataout)==1);
for inan in range(len(JJ)):
    jp,ip = JJ[inan],II[inan]
    # -----------------------------------------------------
    nanmask[jp-n:jp+n+1,ip-n:ip+n+1] = 1.0
# ---------------------------------------------------------
subplot(121);pcolormesh(dataout);
subplot(122);pcolormesh(nanmask);show()
```

So, I will detect the mask of nan values and then mark neighbouring locations around each nan point. Not very fancy solution, but seems to work.

Comment: Thank you, it work and it is fairly fast on larger datasets.